# Python cumulative return groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following long format dataset:

```
   data = [['x',0.02],['x',0.03],['x',0],['x',-0.03],['y',0.05], 
   ['y',-0.03],['y',0],['y',-0.01]]
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['asset', 'return'])
```

I want to create a new column with cumulative returns which group by the asset.

I have tried:

```
df.set_index('asset', append=True).assign(cumreturn=df.groupby('asset')['return'].rolling(1,min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: np.cumproduct(1+x)).swaplevel(0,1)).reset_index(1)
```

but it seems lengthy and does not return the correct values.

any ideas on efficient way to produce cumulative returns here with groupby().
the correct output should be:

[image: output]

even better would be to get it all in long and tidy format:

[image: tidy output]

Comment: `df.groupby('asset')['return'].cumsum()`?

Comment: No that is not the cumulative return, should be cum product (i.e. you don't calculate return on return with cumsum)

Comment: Well then `cumprod`. We don't have the context, so whitout more details we're just guessing...

Comment: yes but with cumprod it does not work. what more details would you like to see?

Comment: expected output usually helps

Comment: @yatu fair point. I added the desired output above

Comment: There seems to be an error in the expected output as well, the cum_return values are 0.02, 0.051... in first table while in second they are 0.05, -0.03 etc

Comment: Can you describe in plain english what the desired operation is? how are 0.02 and 0.03 (first 2 values of x) resulting in 0.051, second value of cum_return for x

Comment: @AkshaySehgal cumulative return is return on return. if you invest 1 unit today and tomorrow it returns 1% and the day after 1% then your cumulative return is: 1*(1.01)^2 - 1 which is more than the cumsum (2%)

Comment: @JelleJansen just edited my answer, it gives the expected output.

Comment: Ok great, how are you ending up with 0.051 ? could you give a quick calculation

Comment: (1+0.02)*(1+0.03)-1, which is rounded to 0.051

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, with `np.cumprod`:

```
df['cum_return']=df.groupby('asset').apply(lambda x: np.cumprod(1 + x) - 1).round(3)
```

Actually, your original solution will work if you change `np.cumproduct` to `np.prod`:

```
df.set_index('asset', append=True).assign(cumreturn=df.groupby('asset')['return']                                       
                                  .rolling(1,min_periods=1).apply(lambdax: np.prod(1+x))
                                  .swaplevel(0,1)).reset_index(1)
```

Output:

```
df
  asset  return  cum_return
0     x    0.02       0.020
1     x    0.03       0.051
2     x    0.00       0.051
3     x   -0.03       0.019
4     y    0.05       0.050
5     y   -0.03       0.018
6     y    0.00       0.018
7     y   -0.01       0.008
```

---

And, to get the second format, you could try:

```
temp=df.groupby('asset').apply(lambda x: list((np.cumprod(1 + np.array(x)) - 1).round(3))).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})
temp.insert(1,column='type',value='cum_return')

temp2=df.groupby('asset').agg(list).reset_index().rename(columns={'return':'value'})
temp2.insert(1,column='type',value='return')

df=pd.concat([temp2,temp]).sort_values(by=['asset']).explode('value')
```

Output:

```
  asset        type  value
0     x      return   0.02
0     x      return   0.03
0     x      return      0
0     x      return  -0.03
0     x  cum_return   0.02
0     x  cum_return  0.051
0     x  cum_return  0.051
0     x  cum_return  0.019
1     y      return   0.05
1     y      return  -0.03
1     y      return      0
1     y      return  -0.01
1     y  cum_return   0.05
1     y  cum_return  0.018
1     y  cum_return  0.018
1     y  cum_return  0.008
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer! only thing it misses is the "type column". so in the last long format table you have the column asset and the column return but there should be a type column which defines if the value is a return or cumreturn

Comment: You're welcome!  I misinterpreted the second format. Just edited to get the desired output. If the answer works for you, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'. I just started using Python but I am proficient in R and love Dplyr. compared to running the same operation in R Dplyr this seems quite messy (I hope I'm allowed to say this :) )

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: Pandas version 0.24.2. and now i see its new in version 25

Comment: Maybe that's the reason of the error, as you can see in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), is new in version up to 0.25.0., so, I suggest you to  update pandas version, and then test the solution.

Comment: yes this was the solution. I added points to this answer but haven't put it on solved yet because I would like to see if there is a more efficient and "clean" way of coding this

Comment: @JelleJansen hey, how do you get the second format using R Dplyr? Just for curiosity, maybe I can mould it to python!:)

Comment: With the gather function i would move it to long format and then using mutate I would add the cumulative return. now using this link (https://stmorse.github.io/journal/tidyverse-style-pandas.html) to try to tidy it a bit in Python

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this your exact requirement.

use

```
df['sum']=df.groupby('asset').cumsum()

output :
  asset  return   sum
0     x    0.02  0.02
1     x    0.03  0.05
2     x    0.00  0.05
3     x   -0.03  0.02
4     y    0.05  0.05
5     y   -0.03  0.02
6     y    0.00  0.02
7     y   -0.01  0.01
```

use normal `sum()` if you want the groupby to remain

Comment: No that is not the cumulative return, should be cum product (i.e. you don't calculate return on return with cumsum)

Answer (score 0):

you could break out your data using a loop and calculate the cumulative sum using pandas `cumsum()` function.

```
df_list = []

# Loop over each unique asset 
for asset in set(df.asset.values):
    tmp = df[df.asset == asset].reset_index(drop=True)
    tmp['cumulative_return'] = tmp.asset.cumsum()
    df_list.append(tmp)

new_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```

Comment: No that is not the cumulative return, should be cum product (i.e. you don't calculate return on return with cumsum) + it seems really cumbursome for a cumprod calculation